# Especificar Tamanho do Modal

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Adicionei um modal em meu site, e estou tentando alterar o tamanho do mesmo.
Mas por mais que eu altere o css dele , não aplica no site, estou alterando dentro no arquivo `bootstrap.min.css` do meu site, como na imagem abaixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Podem me ajudar ?

----------------------------Depois da edição -----------------------------
[image: Meu index]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Luis, coloque o seu HTML e o CSS completo que fica mais fácil para te responder. Inclusive com a `<head>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem que fazer um Override na classe **`<div class="modal-dialog">`** do Bootstrap.

```
.modal-dialog {
    width: 400px !important; /* aqui vc coloca a largura que deseja */
    margin: 30px auto;
}
```

Tipo assim:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<style>
    .modal-dialog {
        width: 400px !important; /* aqui vc coloca a largura que deseja */
        margin: 30px auto;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
        
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
        Launch demo modal
      </button>
      
      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: não funcionou, não tenho ideia no que eu estou fazendo errado , pode dar uma olhada na minha pergunta eu deu mais detalhes

Comment: @luismatheus editei minha resposta como uma mudança que pode resolver o problema. Coloquei a largura na classe Pai que eu sugeri anteriormente. Acho que agora vai, testa ai!

Answer (score 2):

Você não deve alterar `bootstrap.min.css`, o que deve ser feito é definir o estilo em seu próprio css que deve ser declarado depois do bootstrap;

Adicione a classe:

```
.modal { 
    width: 700px; 
}
```

Comment: eu alterei mas meu assim não aplica ,